# Scroll to bottom of div in given time

Tags: javascript, scroll

I have multiple text-containing divs stacked below each other that are visible through a roughly 800x800 pixels frame. I am using `element.scrollIntoView(...)` (with smooth behavior) to visually scroll between the divs, but some divs are longer than 800px and thus the div content after 800px is skipped. I want to use JavaScript to scroll down that div (in the likes of `{behavior:'smooth', block:'end'}`) but only in a given time, not instantly (e.g. have it slowly scroll to the bottom for 10 seconds, so all text can be read). How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you want something like this?

```js
$(window).ready(() => {
  let numDivs = 4; // how many divs you have
  let scrollTime = 10000; // how long it would take to scroll to the specified location
  let scrollVal = ($('#first').offset().top) + (($('#second').offset().top)/numDivs);
  $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollVal }, scrollTime);
});
```

```css
.block-small {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 500px;
}

.block-med {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 800px;
}

.block-large {
  padding: 15px;
  height: 1000px;
}

#first {
  background-color: green;
}

#second {
  background-color: red;
}

#third {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="block-small" id="first"></div>
<div class="block-med" id="second"></div>
<div class="block-large" id="third"></div>
```

Also, here's a [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/MzVdba) :)

Comment: Yes, almost! I only want to scroll slowly to the bottom of the first div (wherein I mean that the bottom of the div is visible at the bottom of the given frame), not the top of the second div. After some delay I can quickly jump to the second one because the transition between divs isn't really interesting.

Comment: Hm, this definetly the right direction, but in your Codepen example it scrolls to far (a lot of the red is visible). Is this a problem with Codepen?

Comment: @Bovestesin1984 should be better now :)